# Surjectivity of extension

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Consider (only one part of it)

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces that are dense in Banach spaces $\widetilde{X}$ and $\widetilde{Y}$ respectively, and let $T \in L(X, Y)$. Explain why $T$ extends to a unique $\widetilde{T} \in L(\widetilde{X}, \tilde{Y})$. Show that $\|\widetilde{T}\|=\|T\|$, so that we may regard $L(X, Y)$ as a subspace of $L(\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y})$. Is $L(X, Y)$ dense in $L(\widetilde{X}, \widetilde{Y}) ?$ If $T$ is surjective, must $\widetilde{T}$ be surjective? If $T$ is injective, must $\widetilde{T}$ be injective?

I managed to answer all bits, however, I am not sure about my argument for subjectivity. In particular, I thought that if $T$ is subjective, then so must its extension be. This is the argument that I gave:

Say $y \in  \tilde{Y}  $. By density there exists $(y_n) \in  Y$ such that $y_n \rightarrow  y$. By surjectivity, there exists $ (x_n) \in  X$ such that
\begin{align*}
T (x_n) = y_n.
\end{align*}
If $\left\{x_n \right\}$ has a point of accumulation, say $x,$ then $T(x)=y$. Else $\left\{x_n \right\}$ is a closed set, so by the open mapping theorem, its image is closed. So there exists $N$ such that $T (x_N)=y$.

I was told that the result is in fact false. I am trying to figure out why is my proof wrong. Is this the errenous claim

> If $\left\{x_n \right\}$ has a point of accumulation $x$ then $T(x)=y$.
> This seems to be the only thing that seems could potentially be wrong.

**Question** Where did the argument go wrong?

Comment: The surjectivity may not hold.

Comment: Hi @RyszardSzwarc, apologies if I didn't make my question clear. My question is what is wrong with the argument - I know that the result is not true.

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood your question. I have pointed out your error in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is wrong as $x_n$ does not need to have an accumulation point. See the example below.

Let $X=Y$ consist of sequences with finitely mamy nonzero terms. Then $X$ is dense in $\tilde{X}=\tilde{Y}=\ell^2.$ Define $(Tx)_n=2^{-n}x_n.$ Then $T$ is surjective from $X$ to $Y$ but not surjective on $\ell^2.$ Observe that for the standard basis $e_n$ the sequence $Te_n$ tends to $0,$ but $e_n$ does not have an accumulation point.

Comment: I see now, thank you very much!